# Meteor with Typeahead: where to call typeahead() on input element?

Tags: meteor, bootstrap-typeahead, iron-router

I'm using Meteor with Iron Router, and can't seem to get typeahead (this version: https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) to work.

Here's some code:

```
HomeController = RouteController.extend({
  //....
  after: function () {
    var tags = this.getData().tags;
    console.log(tags);
    if(tags.length > 0) {
      var tags = ['hello', 'world'];
      console.log("Adding typeahead for tags to ", $('.input-search')[0]);
      console.log("tags: ", tags);
      $('.input-search').typeahead({
        source: tags,
        updater: function(item) {
          Router.go('/projects/tag/' + item);
        }
      });
    }
  },
```

I have a header that's part of the application layout, and has an input like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-search" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="Search">
```

The jQuery in the after: function gets the input correctly. But calling typeahead on the input doesn't seem to activate typeahead properly: when typing in the input, nothing happens.

However if I wrap the typeahead call in a setTimeout, it does work.

Of course, whenever you start wrapping things in setTimeouts, something isn't right.

Where/when is the correct place to initialise typeahead when using Iron Router?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the typeahead in the `rendered` function of your template. For instance:

```js
Template.mytemplate.rendered = function() {
      $('.input-search').typeahead({
        source: tags,
        updater: function(item) {
          Router.go('/projects/tag/' + item);
        }
      });
};
```

Comment: I tried this too, and had the same problem: it only works when wrapped in a setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

You need to make sure any inputs used by plugins are "preserved", i.e. not re-rendered, by Meteor. The simplest way to do this is to make sure the input has an ID attribute. So changing my search input to this fixed it:

```
<input type="text" id="input-search" class="form-control" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="Search">
```

Relevant documentation: http://docs.meteor.com/#template_preserve

Answer (score 0):

As of Meteor 1.0.3.1 and iron:router@1.0.7 working solution is to install `sergeyt:typeahead`  and init typeahead like this:

```
Template.MyTemplate.rendered = function () {
    Meteor.typeahead.inject();
}
```

Init may be done only once for top-level template.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article about this, you can read it [here](http://wontonst.blogspot.com/2015/12/guide-to-implementing-typeahead-in.html).

In summary, your implementation using javascript to select and alter the element is bad practice in a reactive environment. I've tried it that way and it's a huge pain.

What I found is that you can create a helper that returns a JSON string of your typeahead data and use the data-source attribute, like so

JS

```
Template.myHelper.helper({
  typeahead : function(){
    return JSON.stringify(Session.get("typeahead"));
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<template name="myTemplate">
    <input data-source="{{typeahead}}" data-provide="typeahead" id="blah" type="text" />
</template>
```